# How do I run a module from a parent class within a child class?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have 2 classes and this is what I want to do.

```
class Parent:
    def something(self):
        return "some text"

class Child(Parent):
    this = returned text of parent.something()
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Hopefully a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the super() function. This allows you to call a function from the inherited class:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def something(self):
        return 'something'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name) # calls the __init__ function of Parent
        self.something = super().something() # calls the something function of Parent


c = Child('John')
something = c.something
name = c.name
print(something, name) # output = something John
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute in the `Child.__init__` method instead, at which point you can simply call `self.something()`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.this = self.something()
```

You cannot call `parent.something()` when defining `Child`, because there is no *instance to call it on*.